# What is the leading edge technology for creating a quantum computer with the fewest errors?

Tags: error-correction, architecture, fault-tolerance

Which technological path seems most promising to produce a quantum processor with a greater [quantum volume](https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/AUTH_039c3bf6e6e54d76b8e66152e2f87877/community-documents/quatnum-volumehp08co1vbo0cc8fr.pdf) (preferring fewer errors per qubit over more qubits), than [Majorana fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion)?

The preferred format for the answer would be similar to:

"Group ABC's method DEF has demonstrated better QV than using MF; as proven independently in paper G on page x, paper H on page y, and paper I on page z".

On [Majorana fermions](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys4110) Landry Bretheau [says](https://news.mit.edu/2017/superconductors-graphene-exotic-electronic-states-quantum-computing-0505):

> These particles could be the elementary brick of topological quantum computers, with very strong protection against errors. Our work is an initial step in this direction.

---

Example of an insufficient (but interesting) answer:

In their paper "[Robust quantum metrological schemes based on protection of quantum Fisher information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4052)", Xiao-Ming Lu, Sixia Yu, and C.H. Oh construct a family of $2t+1$ qubits metrological schemes being immune to $t$-qubit errors after the signal sensing. In comparison at least five qubits are required for correcting arbitrary 1-qubit errors in standard quantum error correction.

[Note: This theory of robust metrological schemes preserves the quantum Fisher information instead of the quantum states themselves against noise. That results in a good effective volume **if** they can construct a device utilizing their techniques and show that it **scales**.

While that might seem like one promising answer it's a single link (without multiple concurring sources) and there's no device built to show scalability. A low qubit device that's error free and unscalable **or** a device with many error-prone qubits has a low volume (and thus is "Not An Answer").]

---

Additional references:

Paper explaining [Quantum Volume](https://ibm.biz/BdiaQe).

[image: Qubits vs. Error Rate]

After doing some research it looks like Graphene sandwiched between superconductors to produce Majorana fermions is the leading edge - is there something better? ["better" means currently possible,  not theoretically possible or ridiculously expensive]. The graphic illustrates that over a hundred qubits with less 0.0001 error rate is wonderful,  lesser answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 12):

That is indeed the most important question at the moment!

[Superconducting qubits](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/devices) currently have the biggest devices. But will they continue to scale? Will short coherence times make it too hard for error correction to keep up?

[Trapped ions](https://physicsworld.com/a/ion-trap-quantum-computer-is-programmable-and-reconfigurable/) are not far behind. But they have their own [scalability issues](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/339/6124/1164).

[Spin qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5917) should be great for scaling once they get going. They are still down in the [few qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04214) at the moment, though.

Majoranas also are suspected to have some nice properties. But I’d have to see a single qubit before I declare them to be the leading edge.

Photonics are also a viable strategy. In fact, [the first cloud based quantum device](http://cnotmz.appspot.com/) was photonic. A few startups are also based around photonic based approaches, such as the one described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08535).

Comment: I enjoyed reading your answer but over 5 years have passed since and I am sure there has been progress.  I would love to hear your comments and/or answer to my recent post https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34055/what-is-the-optimal-hardware-for-quantum-computing-and-what-factors-contribute?noredirect=1#comment45017_34055